# glDeleteBuffers() crashes during destructor call

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

As Qt users know, using any OpenGL extensions can  be quite troublesome. The way I made it work is to extends QGLFunctions class like so:

```
 class Object3D : protected QGLFunctions{ 
 ... 
 }
```

In order for Object3D to function correctly such that it can call functions like glGenBuffer() etc. one needs to call

```
initializeGLFunctions(glWidget->context());
```

AFTER QGLWidget has been created or else it would simply crash the application when it uses any extension functions. While I can finally call "glGenBuffer()" and others during the existence of Object3D, it seems to crash upon ~Object3D() call which contains "glDeleteBuffer()" call. I am sure it is that call that makes the application crashes.

Anyone know how to solve this problem? I suspect it is because QGLWidget is being deleted first before Object3D and so the context of QGLWidget is gone. If that's the case, how can I make sure QGLWidget is deleted last since QGLWidget is added to QMainWindow which simply deletes its children in the order they are added?

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is, if you can't *guarantee* that the OpenGL RAII object will be destroyed while the context is still around, then don't wrap OpenGL objects inside RAII C++ classes. Manage the lifetime of OpenGL objects in other ways.

It's your code (which you neglected to show us); only you can decide where or how to manage the destruction of classes. You need some system to manage your objects that will ensure that things are destroyed (and created) in the proper order.

Comment: It's just that in Qt, I have to implement QGLFunctions class to get pointers to the extensions. The initialization of that requires a QGLWidget's context. While I can create objects that uses those functions, it seems in their destructor, calling "glDeleteBuffer()" causes a crash. Would this still be the case that I need to centralize the deletion?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon: There's no rule in QT that says you *have* to use their interface. You only have to if you want your code to work on desktop GL and GL ES without doing the work of implementing it yourself. Furthermore, you don't *implement* the class; you *use it*. You create an instance of it, and *every* place in your code that wants to call them uses that instance. You don't derive from it.

Comment: While I see what you are saying, I have tried not using their QGLFunctions class and it did not work. I tried to integrate glew.h into the application but it simply won't compile. I even tried writing my own QGLFunctions class that gets all the correct pointers to the extensions and that simply crashes the application when I call any extension functions (at least this compiled). So I am left with using QGLFunctions. Is there any easier way to not use QT's GL extensions?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon: It's kind of hard to diagnose a problem with no details beyond "I tried X and it didn't work". If you want to investigate alternatives, try them, and if it breaks, ask here about why it did in a new question.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon: Also, that ignores the main issue, which is that you're deriving your Object class from it, which makes no sense. As I said, you create a single QGLFunctions instance and make it available to whomever you want to use it.