# Unitialized read and unaddressable access errors

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, memory-management

I executed drmemory under Windows 7 to check my memory leaks and found something rather odd to me:

```
Error #1: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x08842fdc-0x08842fe0 4 byte(s)
# 0 ig7icd32.dll!DllMain                             +0x56017  (0x5a995ec7 <ig7icd32.dll+0xd5ec7>)
# 1 ig7icd32.dll!DllMain                             +0x54bad  (0x5a994a5e <ig7icd32.dll+0xd4a5e>)
# 2 AbstractVertexData::vertexAttribPtr               [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/Engine/Graphics/AbstractVertexData.cpp:36]
# 3 DrawBuffers::buildBuffers                         [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/Engine/Graphics/DrawBuffers.cpp:49]
# 4 DrawBuffers::DrawBuffers                          [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/Engine/Graphics/DrawBuffers.cpp:14]
# 5 Core::Load                                        [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/Engine/Core/Load.cpp:178]
# 6 main                                              [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/main.cpp:10]
```

This errors points to this code and more precisely to the last line:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(layout,
                      getShaderAttribs()[layout]->nbComponents,
                      static_cast<GLenum>(getShaderAttribs()[layout]->attribDataType),
                      getShaderAttribs()[layout]->shouldNormalize,
                      getVertexStride(layout),
                      reinterpret_cast<const void*>(getVertexAttribStart(layout)));
```

What OpenGL wants from the last parameter is a const GLvoid* (const void*). It is semantically an int which indicates the offset of an attribute array. Anyway, this line works perfectly fine but I would like to get rid of this warning. I can't use references because the function getVertexAttribStart returns a value and not a pointer. I also don't want to use C type casting because it kills children in Africa (you know, C is the devil ahah).

There is also this warning:

```
Error #4: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond heap bounds: reading 0x0863fcc4-0x0863fcc8 4 byte(s)
# 0 ig7icd32.dll!DllMain                   +0x52721  (0x5a9925d1 <ig7icd32.dll+0xd25d1>)
# 1 ig7icd32.dll!DllMain                   +0x52660  (0x5a992511 <ig7icd32.dll+0xd2511>)
# 2 ig7icd32.dll!DllMain                   +0x516e7  (0x5a991598 <ig7icd32.dll+0xd1598>)
# 3 DrawBuffers::~DrawBuffers               [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/Engine/Graphics/DrawBuffers.cpp:23]
# 4 DrawBuffers::~DrawBuffers               [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/Engine/Graphics/DrawBuffers.cpp:26]
# 5 Core::Unload                            [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/Engine/Core/Unload.cpp:6]
# 6 main                                    [D:/CodeBlocks Workspace/Tests/BasicScene_Tests/BasicScene_InitialTest/main.cpp:23]
```

And the code for this warning:

```
DrawBuffers::~DrawBuffers()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo); // I'm the line 23!!!
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    delete vertexData;
}
```

First of, what are the vao, vbo and ibo variables? They are integers; actually indices in OpenGL that points to some data in the VRAM (I'm no expert). They are guaranteed to be initialized and are only destroyed in this destructor. The proof is that my application works perfectly fine. Is there a way to fix this drmemory's warning or get rid of it?

Here's conception of my engine (you need draw.io): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5dq0OS4n55JcHJqcTBmZHJWYjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: By the way, why don't you just write something like `getVertexAttribStartAddr (layout)` that returns a `const GLvoid *`? You _could_ think of this parameter as an `int`, but I would advise against that for portability. GL expects an integer value with as many bits as your host's data pointer type. `intptr_t` is basically the type you would use for this.

Comment: Hmmm I just tried it and I kind of need to cast my intptr_t even if it's in a return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time but I had forgotten something really important:

> The general rule is, if you can't guarantee that the OpenGL RAII object will be destroyed while the context is still around, then don't wrap OpenGL objects inside RAII C++ classes.
>   [glDeleteBuffers() crashes during destructor call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336729/gldeletebuffers-crashes-during-destructor-call)

In my main loop, I was closing the window, i.e. the context, before unloading the data.

Answer (score 4):

> First of, what are the vao, vbo and ibo variables? They are integers; actually indices in OpenGL that points to some data in the VRAM (I'm no expert). They are guaranteed to be initialized and are only destroyed in this destructor. The proof is that my application works perfectly fine. Is there a way to fix this drmemory's warning or get rid of it?

While not related to your problem, it might help to know that `vao`, `vbo` and `ibo` are *reserved names* in OpenGL. They do not technically have to be associated with any data (they will exist in this state immediately after calling `glGenBuffers (...)` or `glGenArrays (...)`, but before binding them). There is no simple analog in a language like C++, because if you `new` some object in C++ it will call the constructor immediately - GL defers construction of objects until a name is first bound.

As for your actual problem, you are invoking the destructor for your class twice. I have no idea why this is happening with what little code you have shown, but it explains why taking the address of `vbo` is yielding an invalid heap address.

Comment: Actually, the destructor is only called once. I just debugged it and it makes sense. I have a DrawBuffers variable that I create in Load.cpp and destroy in Unload.cpp. BUT! I just noticed something: is it a problem if I delete my shader before deleting my vao, vbo and ibo?

Comment: Also, my code is HUGE. I mean, there are a lot of code line's and I don't know the best way to give it to you and show you where everything is. *Huge is relative

Comment: Ok I just retested and you were right, the destructor is called twice. Strangely, when I put breakpoints everywhere, the first time it stops at the end of the destructor and then the next time goes to the top.